# OPNsense Ssh root@IPaddress "ssh: connect to host port (ANY PORT NUMBER): Operation time out"

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, opnsense

Hello everyone I hope you're all great!

I'll try to be as abstract and clear as possible.

I'm working on OPNsense using Virtual Box on mac, everything used to work fine and I could simply login via my terminal in mac using

```
ssh root@IPaddress
```

However, and out of no where the message

```
ssh: connect to host port 22: Operation timed out
```

had appeared and I no longer can log in my opnsense from my terminal. I've tried many solutions including:

1)

```
ssh root@IPaddress -p 2222
ssh root@IPaddress -p ANY PORT NUMBER
```

no matter what port number I'm using it produce the same problem, the meassage will just have the port number that I've used.

2) Changing my private sshd_config

I've tried enabling DNS from the sshd, I've even copied the sshd_config and ssh_config files of a another computer that works fine and replace it in my mac and it didn't work.

3) I've tried the port forwarding in the network settings in my virtual box and specified guest port to 22 and host port to 2222.

4) I tried different local ip addresses.

5) I restored my opnsense to its factory settings, rebooted it many times, reinstalled it, restarted my computer a 100 time :)

I want to point out that the opnsense works fine in the browser when I go to:

```
https://IPaddress
```

I can sign in and do everything that I need, it only doesn't work when I try to log in using my terminal with the ssh.

Could someone helps me?

Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access the OPNsense web UI means that your system is able to communicate with OPNsense without any issues.

Inorder to work SSH, you have to enable certain options in OPNSense system administration.

Please refer the screenshot and make sure the 3 checkboxes are ticked.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLHHZ.png)